# trace32 - How can I load multiple non-consecutive addresses into axf

Tags: trace32

Based on CORTEXA7

symbol is *.axf
and The code dumps some data and saves it in *.mem, but the data is discontinuous

now How to load *.mem to match symbol

for example, use the cmm command, will load from 0x8160000
.load.binary "&mem_file_path" 0x81600000 /noclear

But the data saved in this *.mem file may be
0x81600000~ 0x81700000
0x82600000~ 0x82700000
0x83600000~ 0x83700000

Is there any way I can load the data in mem mapped to different areas of axf？

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.... 
Can you try to improve the quality of your question?

Comment: Hi, This requirement is my own understanding of the mistake.  Can you also help me see another question?     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73062919/run-a-cmm-file-in-trace32-icd-arm32-sim-using-python         Thanks